# Polynomial time reduction from a language not in $\mathcal{NP}$

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

Is it true that a language $L \notin \mathcal{NP}$ can not be reduced (in polynomial time) to a language in $Q \in \mathcal{NP}$ ?
My take is that because the reduction has to be polynomial in time, i can't take in input a non NP problem, but i can't formalize my thoughts.

The question is part of a larger question where i have to prove that if $\mathcal{NP} \neq \mathcal{co-NP}$ then SAT is not reducible to UNSAT.

Comment: It would be better if you could explain your larger question for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $Q \in \mathcal{NP}$ (so there is non-determenistic Turing machine $T$ that solves it in polynomial time) and $L$ is polynomial reducible to $Q$. Then there is a non-determenistic machine $T'$ (defined as "apply reduction and launch $T$) that solves $L$ in (non-determenistic) polynomial time, thus $L \in \mathcal{NP}$.

Formally, the deduction is as follow:

1. $Q \in \mathcal{NP}$ (given)
2. $\neg(L \in \mathcal{NP})$ (given)
3. $Q \in \mathcal{NP} \rightarrow ((L \leq_P Q) \rightarrow (L \in \mathcal{NP})$ (proven above, $\leq_P$ means polinomaly reducible)
4. $(L \leq_P Q) \rightarrow (L \in \mathcal{NP})$ (m.p. from 1 and 3)
5. $\neg(L \in \mathcal{NP}) \rightarrow \neg (L \leq_P Q)$ (contraposition)
6. $\neg (L \leq_P Q)$ (m.p. from 2 and 5)

Comment: What have you proved?

Comment: That if $L$ is reducible to language in NP then $L$ is in NP itself. Equally, if $L$ is not in NP, then it is not reducible to language in NP.

Comment: Are you sure about that? we have proved in class that "if $L_1$ is reducible to $L_2$ and $L_2$ is decidable then $L_1$ is decidable". Then the negation is the following, "if $L_1$ is reducible to $L_2$ and $L_1$ is undecidable then $L_2$ is undecidable". Now i'm aware that $A\rightarrow B \equiv \neg B \rightarrow \neg A$ but L reducible to Q is the general hypothesisand should not be negated, what am i missing?

Comment: I wrote the next steps in more details, hope it's clearer. Less formally, we proven that if $L$ is reducible to $Q$ and $Q$ is in $NP$ then $L$ is in $NP$; we know that $L$ is not in $NP$ so either it's not reducible to $Q$ or $Q$ is not in $NP$, but as we are given that $Q$ is in $NP$ the only possibility left is $L$ is not reducible to $Q$.

Comment: it's very, very clear, thank you. One thing i don't understand though is the "general hypotesis" things i have mentioned, we know that $A \rightarrow B \equiv \neg B \rightarrow \neg A$", so why do we take A reducible to B as something to not negate in the theorem i stated above? if i think about it i will say something like you did (if $L_1$ is undecidable $\rightarrow$ $L_1$ is not reducible to $L_2$ or $L_2$ is undecidable). i fill i am missing something logic-side.

Comment: I am not sure what the "general hypothesis" mean, I don't think I have ever encountered such term. The reasoning you cited about decidability is the same: if $L_1$ is undecidable then either it is not reducible to $L_2$ or $L_2$ is undecidable - from this by pure proposition calculus follows that if $L_1$ is undecidable and reducible to $L_2$ then $L_2$ is undecidable.

Comment: YES! thank you so much, actually i made up the term "general hipothesys" because professor just said that it was the contrapositive so i thought that "A reducible to B" was a sort of higher hipothesys that should not be negated, but this thing was bugging me in a logical sense and you solved my issue. Now everything is clear, even some other theorems that used the same approach, thanks.